# How to split string having '|' symbol in java script?

Tags: javascript

I have string like

```
var result = 'Zika NAA, Blood|Zika NAA, Urine'
```

My requirement is

```
var result = Zika NAA, Blood

              Zika NAA, Urine
```

`|` symbol shouldn't be there and Zika NAA, Urine should come in new line. How to achieve in react js ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with React.

Comment: i have used  result.split('|').join('<br>'));

Comment: its not working br is coming in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```js
 var str = "Zika NAA, Blood|Zika NAA, Urine";
    var res = str.split("|").join("\n");
    console.log(res)
```